# Core Location and Core Motion device heading

Tags: iphone, core-location, gyroscope, core-motion

I've noticed one problem with Coree Motion. When I'm using the

```
   [_mMotionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame: CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical
                       toQueue: [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease]
                   withHandler:
         ^(CMDeviceMotion* motion, NSError* error) {
//my code here
    }];
```

to get device motion it gives me wrong device heading. I mean if I start processing motion updates holding device towards the north the heading is OK. But if I start not towards the north the bias is very big.

Is there any way to get correct values of heading?

Answer (score -1):

Have you read the documentation?

It says that the values can be incorrect and that the user would have to move the device to calibrate the magnetometer.

So I guess you cannot rely on that reference frame.

Comment: Yep, but that doesn't help